# jGRASP wedge: could not execute python3

Tags: python-3.x, jgrasp

I am trying to use jGrasp to run python3 for debugging purposes, but it is throwing the error below when I try to run my program [image: jGrasp RUN I/O output]I have downloaded python3 and I made sure it works in the terminal, but for some reason it is not working in jGrasp. It might have something to do with the PATH but I don't know what location I should add for jGrasp to be able to execute it properly.

Answer (score 0):

The Python path should end with "bin", not "bin/python3". Paths need to be directories that contain executable files, not the executable files themselves. Whether you have added this path in jGRASP only, or at the OS level, you need to change it.